# Unmatch indices on elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch with quite a large number of different indices (>300)  and for some of my queries I would like to be able to discard indices based on the fact that they contain a certain substring. I do not want to write their explicit names because some have a common prefix/suffix/GUID. Is there some syntax that would lead to the following pseudo-code below?

```
my_request = es.search(index='*all_indices*' EXCEPT 'suffix1, suffix2',body=query)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use wildcards while deleting indices.

```
curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/*,-*suffix1,-*suffix2
```

This will delete ALL indicies (`*`) except (`-`) indices that ends with `suffix1` or `suffix2`.

By minus sign (`-`) you are removing given indices from the list, aby by asterisk `*` you are matching all indices in your cluster.

More on that:

- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/multi-index.html
- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-delete-index.html